# How to divide any sized image to equal sized block using only for loop in matlab?

Tags: image, matlab, block

**How to divide image to equal sized blocks using simple matlab for loop only?**
As a beginner I have tried but its showing error.I have done same thing using `mat2cell` and using simple calculation.

This is my code:

```
[rows, columns, numberOfColorChannels] = size(p); 
r4 = int32(rows/4); 
c4 = int32(columns/4); 
% Extract images. 
image1 = p(1:r4, 1:c4); 
image2 = p(1:r4, c4+1:2*c4); 
image3 = p(1:r4, 2*c4+1:3*c4); 
image4 = p(1:r4, 3*c4+1:4*c4);
```

I need to do it with a for loop only.

Comment: Please share what errors are you getting and the code you have written.

Comment: p = rgb2gray(imread('foreman001.png'));

%p = imread('img.png'); % Read in image.
% Figure out where to divide it.
[rows, columns, numberOfColorChannels] = size(p);
r4 = int32(rows/4);
c4 = int32(columns/4);
% Extract  images.
image1 = p(1:r4, 1:c4);
image2 = p(1:r4, c4+1:2*c4);
image3 = p(1:r4, 2*c4+1:3*c4);
image4 = p(1:r4, 3*c4+1:4*c4);

Comment: @ritesh its using simple way..i need to do using for loop

Comment: I have little idea about matlab. I am just trying to help you write questions in a way that others can help you. Hope this will be of help: http://catb.org/esr/faqs/smart-questions.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First things first if you separate x and y into 4 equally sized sections you will get 16 smaller images. You need to understand this first part.

```
[rows, columns, numberOfColorChannels] = size(p); 
r4 = int32(rows/4); 
c4 = int32(columns/4); 
output = zeros(16,r4,c4,numberOfColorChannels);
cnt = 1;
for i=1:4,
   for j=1:4,
      output(cnt,:,:,:) = p((i-1)*r4+1:i*r4, (j-1)*c4+1:j*c4); 
      cnt = cnt + 1;
   end
end
```

The code basically does what you've already done but in two dimensions.

Comment: it was a great help i need to know this line  output = zeros(16,r4,c4,numberOfColorChannels);in the loop it will misses out 2 pts in 3rd iteration and 3 pts in 4th iteration .will that be a problem

Comment: how to do the same for 2 images